# rails controller variables is persistent across requests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I accidentally overwrote the `controller.controller_name` variable in one of the app views, I excepted the variable value to reset in new requests but that did not happen, the `controller.controller_name` returns the new value on every request. the controller and the action are nearly empty, this is the Home controller file `controllers/home_controller.rb`:

```rb
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def firstroute
    render 'home/secondroute'
  end   
end
```

and this is the `views/secondroute.html.erb` file:

```html
<b>In <i><%= request.path %></i> route, controlled at: <i><%= controller.controller_name.concat("/").concat(controller.action_name) %><b>
```

I overwrote `controller.controller_name` in the `concat()` call, I should have been used `+` operator instead.

**is this an intended behavior on rails or only for some variables? if so how can I reset it without restarting the server ?**

Comment: Instead of modifying the `controller_name`, you can always save the value in a variable and do any string manipulation with it.

Comment: Yes, this would be the intended behavior in production where classses are eager loaded and persisted across requests. I do realize that you don't want to restart the server but the solution here is to deploy a new version of your app without the defect and restart the rails server.

Comment: "intended behavior on rails" this is the intended behavior of `String#concat` which is to mutate the receiver.